# Run Windows Media Player in Fullscreen in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-media-player

I have a bat file which plays a .mp4 video in Media Player:

```
"C:\program files\windows media player\wmplayer" "\\fileshare1\videos$\video.mp4" /fullscreen
```

This command does not work in PowerShell, does anyone know the correct syntax?

```
Start-Process "\\fileshare1\videos$\video.mp4" -WindowStyle Maximized
```

Comment: I think I know, but what is the error that you get?

Comment: If it's not working, it's probably because you don't have a default program set for `.mp4` files, or it's being locked since you're trying to open a file across the network.

Comment: Your first command will also work in PowerShell if you prefix the command line with `&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/fullscreen` is a command line argument, that is parsed by Windows Media player. So when invoking it from PowerShell you need to pass this argument

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' "Path/to/video.mp4" /fullscreen
```

References:

- [WMPlayer Command Line Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd562624(v=vs.85).aspx)